# Issues with using PHP Swift Mailer

Tags: php, include, require, swiftmailer

What I have done:

1. ) Downloaded Swift-4.1.5.tar
2. ) Extracted it
3. ) Uploaded to my host in /public_html/domain/lib using FileZilla
4. ) Made a new script using the code below.
5. ) Opened it in the Browser and I got the following error below

So my question is, how am I getting the error that the file doesn't exist if It's 100% there? Thanks!

```
    <?php

      require_once '/public_html/domain/lib/swift_required.php';

    ?>
```

Warning: require_once(/public_html/domain/lib/swift_required.php) [function.require-once]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/myuser/public_html/domain/email.php on line 5

Fatal error: require_once() [function.require]: Failed opening required '/public_html/domain/lib/swift_required.php' (include_path='.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php') in /home/myuser/public_html/domain/email.php on line 5

Here's a screenshot of my dir from FileZilla.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/yvWtM.jpg

Comment: By starting a path with a slash you specify an absolute path starting at system root. your filezilla just shows a path relative to your servers document root.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is wrong:

```
// this is absolute path, just like /home/user or /var/www
require_once '/public_html/domain/lib/swift_required.php';
```

Use instead:

```
// this is relative path to the current file
require_once 'public_html/domain/lib/swift_required.php'; //notice: no '/' in the beggining
```

OR:

```
// so use this one if you know the whole path to the file
require_once ABSOLUTE_PATH_TO . 'public_html/domain/lib/swift_required.php';
```

OR:

```
// or use this one if you don't know the whole path
// or if the path will change (dev machine and production machine)
require_once dirname(__FILE__) . RELATIVE_PATH_TO . 'public_html/domain/lib/swift_required.php';
```

Comment: It's weird but even without the backslash at the beginning it did not work. I fixed it by using 'lib/swift_required.php' I will accept your answer in 5 minutes, thanks.

Comment: its realtive to the location of the file your calling it in, always using the absolute path is a good idea.